# Why need bubble sorting?

Tags: bubble-sort

After learning bubble sorting, I learned other sorting.
And then I thought, there are other good sorting, do we need bubble sorting?

In the worst case, the Time Complexity is O(n²)
Even in the best case, Time Complexity is O(n²)
Is there a reason why need this kind of bubble sorting?

Comment: If we didn't have bubble sorting what would all you beginners learn first, to then be taught about better sorting algorithms and why they are better than bubble sorting?  Perhaps more seriously, all that fancy asymptotic complexity abstracts away constant terms and multipliers (so `O(n^2) == 125+O(5.7n^2)`, etc) and it's not too difficult to make examples where some asymptotically worse-algorithms outperform their betters on small problems when run on actual computers, and not on the (again) abstract computers that asymptotic analysis concerns itself with.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bubble sort is easy to understand and implement. It is not very efficient, but it can be useful in certain situations, such as when the data is nearly sorted or when the input is very small.

Bubble sort can be easily adapted to sort lists of data that are stored in other data structures, such as linked lists

Bubble sort is a stable sorting algorithm, which means that it preserves the relative order of items with equal keys.